# TFS Configuration Error

Tags: sql, tfs

I am facing a problem that when i try to configure my TFS it show me the following Error Message

### Error

TF255049: A connection cannot be made to the server that is running SQL Server. Verify that you have entered the correct name for the server, including the instance name, that the server you are attempting to connect to is online, and that you have the required permissions to connect. If you are attempting to connect to the remote SQL Server instance, then verify that it is configured to allow remote connections, that TCP/IP protocol is both enabled and configured to use port 1433 (default), and that Windows Firewall does not block this port.

Comment: All Services including SQL Server, Analysis and browser are running

Comment: When i try to connect my sql server via management studio, its working fine

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting steps provided in the error message?

Comment: Which version of TFS do you try to configure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the SQL version is supported by the TFS version: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#sql-server
2. Check the permission of the account that you use, and make sure it belongs to **SysAdmin Server Role**.
3. As @Daniel mentioned in comment, follow the troubleshooting steps provided in the error message, and check this blog to see whether it is helpful: https://elhajj.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/workaround-error-tf255049-punching-a-hole-through-windows-firewall/

Comment: Firewall is off and second SQL server and team foundation server are supported too.

Comment: Does the account you configure TFS belong to SysAdmin Server Role?  Have you followed the troubleshooting steps provided in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I was running an upgrade from TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps 2020.

After the server restart, the Azure DevOps Server Configuration wizard opened.
I was logged in as the local machine administrator and got this error (TF255049: A connection cannot be made to the server that is running SQL Server...) when trying to connect to my SQL Server machine (to chose the configuration database).

I logged in as Network Administrator, started the wizard again and the SQL connection worked.

To restart the Azure DevOps Configuration Wizard again...
Open the Azure DevOps Administration Console and choose Configure Installed Features to open the Server Configuration Wizard...
[image]